# Weird issue with Apple Pay

Tags: macos, apple-pay, startup

From this morning, for some reason I see this message when I go to use Apple Pay on my Mac:

[image]

I have no idea what's wrong with it, and I checked the security boot in recovery and it's set to Full.

I didn't tweak or mess with the system, I have home-brew install but that's about it.

Any ideas?

- firewall on
- 2FA on on Apple ID
- secure boot at full
- Never issues before
- Filevault on since day 1
- MBP 16inch with Bootcamp installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What a mess Apple software currently is, and I'm using it since Tiger professionally.

The fix was to check this box in Software Update:

[image]